# C++ Sharing member variables to member instances of classes during initialization

Tags: c++

Currently using C++20.

I'm trying to share data from an instance of class `A` to its member instances of `B` and `C` during initialization. Rather than using getter/setters, singletons, dependency injections, etc, I was thinking of just sharing the data by passing them as arguments in the constructors of the member class variables, where each member instance would hold their share of data via some mean (e.g. reference, raw pointer, shared pointer, void pointer, etc).

Classes `B` and `C` are intended to always be initialized as members of class `A`. Ultimately, `A` should be the last 'owner' of the data such that when `A` gets deallocated during destruction, the shared data should be deallocated with it. With that in mind, which of these approaches would be acceptable; not violating any major rules and ensuring encapsulation?

1. `A` stores and passes the data as shared pointers. `B` & `C` stores the arguments as shared pointers.
2. `A` stores the data as normal variables, and passes them as void pointers. `B` & `C` stores the arguments as void pointers.
3. `A` stores the data as normal variables, and passes them as references. `B` & `C` stores the arguments as references.
4. `A` stores the data as normal variables, and passes them as raw pointers. `B` & `C` stores the arguments as raw pointers.

Pseudocode:

```
class B
{
private:
  // Some variable that holds the shared data
};

class C
{
private:
  // Some variable that holds the shared data
};

class A
{
  private:
    // Data to be shared to
    B b;
    C c;

    // Data to be shared
    SomeDataType first;
    SomeDataType second;

  public:
    A()
      : b{first, second}, c{first}
    {

    }
};
```

Comment: 1, 3, 4, but 4 suggests these might be nullptr, which is not the case here. In reality, use 3. Also, there's a 5th, CRTP, depending on what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: why do you think you need smart pointers here? What problem would they solve? Why not raw pointers? Smart poitners help with managing ownership, but here there is nothing to manage. `A` has a member and both `b` and `c` are guaranteed to have no lifetime longer than than the `A` instance

Comment: Use 3. Since b and c get destructed when A gets destructed, no issue would occur with invalid references.

Comment: I would go with option 3). Additionally, I would also declare `first` and `second` before `b` and `c` in order to avoid compiler warnings and prevent errors during initialization/destruction.

Comment: I would not go with 3, because reference members have certain implications (eg no copies) that raw pointers do not have. Raw owning pointers is the ones you need to worry about. Raw non-owning pointers that can never get invalidated are harmless

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number that makes sense. I was just listing whatever I could think of in the spur of the moment

Comment: Also, do you intend to use `B` and `C` without `A`? Who will own the data then?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Then `non_null_ptr` tag for documenting purposes.

Comment: @lorro no, i intend to always initialize `B` and `C` as members of instances of `A`. I've added this to the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `A` stores and passes the data as shared pointers. B & C stores the arguments as shared pointers.

No. `A` owns the data, no ownership is shared. ("[...], `A` should be the last 'owner' of the data such that when `A?  gets deallocated during destruction, the shared data should be deallocated with it.", if it is the last and first then it can be the only one, no need to share.)

> `A` stores the data as normal variables, and passes them as void pointers. B & C stores the arguments as void pointers.

No. `void*` is not a solution to a problem you do not have. When in the past one had to use `void*` there are better alternatives now. Though as there is no need here in the first place this is beyond the scope of this answer.

> `A` stores the data as normal variables, and passes them as references. B & C stores the arguments as references.

No, maybe yes. Reference members have implications. The compiler cannot generate copying for you.

> `A` stores the data as normal variables, and passes them as raw pointers. B & C stores the arguments as raw pointers.

That sounds reasonable. It is raw owning pointers that should be avoided. A raw non-owning pointer that never gets invalid (because the owner is destroyed after observers) is fine. The only phases during which you need to be careful not a not yet valid or not anymore valid pointer is during construction and destruction. It is worth mentioning that during construction of `A` it is ok to take pointers to members, but only after the member has been initialized you may safely dereference the pointer.

Comment: you can copy it while having references - you simply write the copy ctor.

Comment: @lorro right. Not sure how to formulate it better. Actually I always stay with either no copies or no reference members. And I have to admit, I wouldnt know how to implement copies correctly in the presence of reference members.

Comment: Following your logic, I'd still make ctor accept references and then maybe store pointers internally. That communicates that an actual instance is required. Or simply document it - perhaps that's the best.

Comment: @lorro that sounds like a good idea; either have the ctor accept references, or accept pointers and deal with null pointer values manually